# Any method that can restart iPhone?

Tags: iphone, restart

Is there any method that will restart the iPhone on call? It can be an undocumented method (and probably will end up being since I can not find a method like it in the iPhone SDK reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no routine, that I know of in any of the libraries (private or not) to restart the device. That said, if you can call into the kernel you can for sure do it.

Keep in mind of course, that it goes against usability guidelines to be doing this sort of thing. Based on your previous question I answered, you aren't targeting the app store so it's likely never going to be an issue; but still. If you have to reboot the phone, there's a good chance that whatever you're doing to require that, can be done a different way.

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, there isn't a function to do this currently, and there won't be any in the offical SDK.